# How do I integrate the Facebook For Unity SDK with my Unity (Javascript) project

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, unityscript

I have installed the Facebook sdk and noted that all the tutorials are based on Unity games made using c#.There are no example using unity games made with Unityscript.

But what if I want to use the SDK with my Unity Javascript/UnityScript project? Can I?

Basically I'm using UnityScript and as soon as I try to do the simplest piece of code:

FB.Init();

I get a Unknown Identifier :'FB' error.

How do I fix/access the class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Place the FB SDK and files in the Standard Assets folder.. They can then be accessed by .js files

Answer (score 1):

You can also move Facebook's Script folder to Plugins folder then you can use FB Class. My Unity version is 4.5.5p2